# How to Whonix > socks5?

Tags: anonymity, whonix, socks

I've just installed whonix in my ubuntu.

My vpn is working great on host machine and my aim is to make this setup:

me > vpn > whonix/tor > sock5

I do know how to make this happen. Ive installed redsocks following this guide: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnel_Proxy_or_SSH_or_VPN_through_Tor#Tunnel_proxy_through_Tor

But I'm getting stuck right after installation cause I don't know how to config it.

Can someone help me?